# Woocommerce ajax load more and ajax filters

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I found this code for woocommerce load more button and I want to combine it with ajax attributes filter, but the results are not as expected. The load more button loads the products of the next page ignoring the ajax filter.

https://github.com/bassscape/woocommerce-ajax-load-more-products

```
<?php

//-----------------------------------------------------
// [1] Enqueue scripts and add localized parameters
//-----------------------------------------------------
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pp_custom_scripts_enqueue' );
function pp_custom_scripts_enqueue() {

    $theme = wp_get_theme(); // Get the current theme version numbers for bumping scripts to load

    // Make sure jQuery is being enqueued, otherwise you will need to do this.

    // Register custom scripts
    wp_register_script( 'woocommerce_load_more', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/load_more.js', array( 'jquery' ), $theme['Version'], true); // Register script with depenancies and version in the footer

    // Enqueue scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('woocommerce_load_more');

    
    global $wp_query; // Make sure important query information is available
    
    // Use wp_localize_script to output some variables in the html of each WordPress page
    // These variables/parameters are accessible to the load_more.js file we enqueued above
    $localize_var_args = array(
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), // everything about your loop is here
        'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )

    );
    wp_localize_script( 'woocommerce_load_more', 'wp_js_vars', $localize_var_args );

}


//-----------------------------------------------------
// [3] Load More Products with AJAX
//-----------------------------------------------------
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'pp_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'pp_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
function pp_loadmore_ajax_handler(){

    // prepare our arguments for the query
    $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    query_posts( $args );

    if( have_posts() ) :

        // run the loop
        while( have_posts() ): the_post();

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );  // As we are loaded Woocommerce products we use wc_get_template_part 
            //echo '<p>'.get_the_title().'</p>'; // for the test purposes comment the line above and uncomment the below one

        endwhile;

    endif;
    die; // Exit the script, wp_reset_query() required!

}


//-----------------------------------------------------
// [4] Remove Woocommerce pagination as we do not need it any more
//-----------------------------------------------------
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10 );


//-----------------------------------------------------
// [5] Add in our load more products container and button
//-----------------------------------------------------
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'pp_woocommerce_products_load_more', 9 );
function pp_woocommerce_products_load_more(){

    echo '<div id="container_products_more">';
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();
        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
        //echo '<pre>' . var_export($wp_query, true) . '</pre>'; // For testing
        if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) {
            echo '<div id="pp_loadmore_products" class="button">LOAD MORE</div>';
        }
    echo '</div>';

}


//-----------------------------------------------------
// [6] Add a new class to the woocommerce_product_loop, we need this to target it with jQuery in load_more.js
//-----------------------------------------------------
function woocommerce_product_loop_start() { echo '<ul class="products products_archive_grid">'; }
function woocommerce_product_loop_end() { echo '</ul>'; } ?>
```

And Javascript

```
(function($) {
"use strict";
$(function() {

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // [2] Ajax load products - On Click
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    $('#pp_loadmore_products').click(function(){

        var button = $(this),
            data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': wp_js_vars.posts, // that's how we get params from wp_localize_script() function
            'page' : wp_js_vars.current_page
        };

        $.ajax({
            url : wp_js_vars.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler
            data : data,
            related_products : 'no',
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.addClass('loading');
                button.text('LOADING ...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
            },
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) {
                    //console.log('current_page: ' + wp_js_vars.current_page + ' max_page: ' + wp_js_vars.max_page);
                    $('#container_products_more .products_archive_grid').append( data ); // where to insert posts
                    button.removeClass('loading');
                    button.text( 'LOAD MORE' );
                    wp_js_vars.current_page++;

                    if ( wp_js_vars.current_page == wp_js_vars.max_page )
                        button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button
                } else {
                    button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
                }
            }
        });
    });

});}(jQuery));
```

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pp_custom_scripts_enqueue');
function pp_custom_scripts_enqueue()
{

    $theme = wp_get_theme(); 


    wp_register_script('woocommerce_load_more', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/load_more.js', array('jquery'), $theme['Version'], true); 

    wp_enqueue_script('woocommerce_load_more');


    global $wp_query; 
    $localize_var_args = array(
        'posts' => json_encode($wp_query->query_vars), 
        'current_page' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')

    );
    wp_localize_script('woocommerce_load_more', 'wp_js_vars', $localize_var_args);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'pp_loadmore_ajax_handler'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'pp_loadmore_ajax_handler'); 
function pp_loadmore_ajax_handler()
{

    $args = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['query']), true);
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; 
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    query_posts($args);

    if (have_posts()) :

        // run the loop
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();


            // echo '<h3 class="post_title-item"> ' . get_the_title() . '</h3> <hr>';

            wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');  // As we are loaded Woocommerce products we use wc_get_template_part 
        //echo '<p>'.get_the_title().'</p>'; // for the test purposes comment the line above and uncomment the below one

        endwhile;

    endif;
    die; 

}


remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10);

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'pp_woocommerce_products_load_more', 9);
function pp_woocommerce_products_load_more()
{
    global $wp_query;
    echo '<div id="container_products_more">';
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();
    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    //echo '<pre>' . var_export($wp_query, true) . '</pre>'; // For testing
    if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) {
        echo '<div class="pp_loadmore_products-wrapper"><button id="pp_loadmore_products" class="button btn-black">Показати більше</button></div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}

function woocommerce_product_loop_start()
{
    echo '<div class="products products__list products_archive_grid">';
}
function woocommerce_product_loop_end()
{
    echo '</div>';
}
```

load_more.js

```
    (function ($) {
        "use strict";
        $(function () {
    
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            // [2] Ajax load products - On Click
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            $('#pp_loadmore_products').click(function () {
    
                var button = $(this),
                    data = {
                        'action': 'loadmore',
                        'query': wp_js_vars.posts, // that's how we get params from wp_localize_script() function
                        'page': wp_js_vars.current_page
                    };
    
                $

.ajax({
                url: wp_js_vars.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler
                data: data,
                related_products: 'no',
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    button.addClass('loading');
                    button.text('Показати більше ...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $('#container_products_more .products_archive_grid').append(data); // where to insert posts
                        button.removeClass('loading');
                        button.text('Показати більше');
                        wp_js_vars.current_page++;
                        console.log(data);
                        if (wp_js_vars.current_page == wp_js_vars.max_page)
                            button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button

                    } else {
                        button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
}(jQuery));
```

used the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-filter/
it worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).